# How to delete evicted pod from k8s by Linux Cron Job/Kubernetes cron job

Tags: linux

I am trying to delete evicted pod by Linux cron script,but getting below error

Script is `root@k8> cat evicted.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
date
echo "Deleting Evcited Pod"
/usr/local/bin/kubectl get po -A | grep Evicted | awk '{system ("kubectl -n " $1 " delete po " $2)}'
```

Output:

```
sh: kubectl: command not found
sh: kubectl: command not found
sh: kubectl: command not found
sh: kubectl: command not found
sh: kubectl: command not found
sh: kubectl: command not found
sh: kubectl: command not found
sh: kubectl: command not found
sh: kubectl: command not found
sh: kubectl: command not found
sh: kubectl: command not found
sh: kubectl: command not found
sh: kubectl: command not found
sh: kubectl: command not found
sh: kubectl: command not found
sh: kubectl: command not found
```

So any idea ,how can I delete it by linux cron job or k8s cron by running a container

Comment: please format your code in the question, make sure that every character is included, like the # in #!/bin/bash

Comment: That is ok,I missed it iin posting ......                                                            
#!/bin/bash
date
echo "Deleting Evcited Pod"
/usr/local/bin/kubectl get po -A | grep Evicted | awk '{system ("kubectl -n " $1 " delete po " $2)}'

Answer (score 0):

check if `kubectl` (or `/usr/local/bin`) is in the `PATH` and/or try `... | awk '{system ("/usr/local/bin/kubectl -n " $1 " delete po " $2)}'`
Also consider quoting parameters.

Comment: Yes Its worked the last part I changed and it is working now,thanks a lot